WCF on .NET 4.8 doesn't add wsse security headers
I need to add the following WSE soap header to a request to an external web service.
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400673630">
        <wsu:Created>2019-02-08T12:59:00.067Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2019-02-08T13:32:20.067Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400083621">MIIGgjCCBGqgAwIB…</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature Id="SIG-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400583629" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa duo soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400083624">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="duo soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>BwIgcnbARGgMPWeDrjR52LGfEf6j/WcF8eE1MQt/MSQ=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400083625">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="duo soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>NDNJrnpAfEcBvCeNvlk3EhMQy8YkL+86XKPHNHkklag=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400083626">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="duo soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>VZrfhemL9OWCsxmN2x4ymGo8LqhyhN1vDyOaQmmEMcA=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400083627">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="duo" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>wRYqFkSq1EU4D6E2dapniCnXAYW4kPWuZ0k/pKnTnkI=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400083628">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="duo soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
22
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>WFpN2A3HvK+b6j4tdgw/N+0DgHnI4THLyQsz8JnA8jY=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>U3f4vdrlrYtSMJ+zXmJ+RyvWt6gZEF9WoiT7dmD2YbL8SYzztOl/foyKLbj9fs8yEqGOL7YEZmev RrQxfePZ7FhP/dW7kBHkhXrUrzYakEA3Tdl21vPwtdNeq0NS9DzASUMPMdWESTDo+qDdzN4HO7MD H4ZQFa8ZuIrJ4Kuo46Ha7Lx/LH2uM0dJBR/XA49LrDqecmdwxV7poELoqsVv4v0kF9iuQI6eeqnW fjDveJ7C/aF1xwl+BB/vtJlaZrd1r9GAsgfZCEfOlLdaTkqGYPd8flQuBaf9hBfY+RKJSFfMmgz4 kaax0DumfavDnTrZ8fn2iI4dlEW10EkLqMqFfg==</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400083622">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400083623">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-BA5FAF729341A20EE515496307400083621" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>

I believe this is some kind of standard WS Security. After following dozens of "examples" on stack, github and blogs, I am utterly confused. It seems about every version of WCF/.NET combo has different capabilities, different structure etc. No example just works.
I got as far as this:
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

     ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
     (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
     {
         return true;
     };
     ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

     WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
     binding.Security = new WSHttpSecurity()
     {
         Mode = SecurityMode.Transport,
         Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
         {
             ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate,
         }
     };

     binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
     binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
     binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
     binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
     binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256;
     
     
     //https://xml-test.duo.nl:6990/vsv-webservice/services/DUO_RelatiefVerzuim_V13
     EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://xml-test.duo.nl:6990/vsv-webservice/services/DUO_RelatiefVerzuim_V13");

     DuoClient duoClient = new DuoClient(binding, endpointAddress);
     

     duoClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("D:\\Temp\\*******.pfx", "**********");
     duoClient.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new LoggingEndpointBehavior());

     try
     {
         using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(duoClient.InnerChannel))
         {
             OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.To = new Uri("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous?oin=00000001800866472000");
             OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.From = new EndpointAddress("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous?oin=0000000700025MB00000");
             OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.MessageId = new System.Xml.UniqueId(Guid.NewGuid());
             //OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Action = "http://duo.nl/contract/DUO_Ping_V1/ping";

             // One-way
             var response = duoClient.meldenRelatiefVerzuim_V7(new MeldenRelatiefVerzuim_V7_Request()
             {
                 bRIN = "",
                 contactpersoon = new Contact()
                 {
                     contactnaam = "",
                     emailadres = "",
                     functieContact = "",
                     telefoonnummer = ""
                 }
             });

             //OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Add(new LoggingEndpointBehavior());


             // Done with service.
             duoClient.Close();
             Console.WriteLine("Done!");
             Console.ReadLine();
         }



     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
     }
     Console.ReadKey();
 }

Example of the output:
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://duo.nl/contract/DUO_RelatiefVerzuim_V13/meldenRelatiefVerzuim_V7</a:Action>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous?oin=00000001800866472000</a:To>
    <a:From>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous?oin=0000000700025MB00000</a:Address>
    </a:From>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:96c4c3c5-73f2-4f7a-849a-3a5613d1a4c4</a:MessageID>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="33dd0450-26cd-4529-93f4-8b37ca3ecb57" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">61878aaf-b8d7-4bc0-800f-26a25c3e8b29</ActivityId>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <meldenRelatiefVerzuim_Request xmlns="http://duo.nl/schema/DUO_RelatiefVerzuim_V13">
      <datumTijdBedrijfsdocument>0001-01-01T00:00:00</datumTijdBedrijfsdocument>
      <bRIN />
      <contactpersoon>
        <contactnaam />
        <functieContact />
        <telefoonnummer />
        <emailadres />
      </contactpersoon>
    </meldenRelatiefVerzuim_Request>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Whatever I change no MessageCredential is added, I even tried normal username password MessageCredential, but nothing ever gets added to the request message. Almost if I am missing a switch to turn it on.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Edit: I tried it on .NET 8.0 to but there is very little example code on how WCF works in .NET 8. I couldn't even get TLS to work on .NET 8. The server certificate is self-signed and I need to override the validation which didn't work. At least not like it does in .NET 4.8 or any of the online examples.

Have you tried using IClientMessageInspectortor  and add header to message in BeforeSendRequest method? This can allow you to add a custom header.

@Jiayao Though that might be a possibility, I use on to log the requests, it would require a lot of signing en certificate stuff I would not know how to do myself. And everything I read says that WCF should just be able to do this. But I tried WSE with a basic credential and cannot even get that to work. Somehow the WSE elements are never added.

Turns out the headers for WS-Security are added later in the process then the messageinspector.
I needed to properly configre the diagnostic tracing to see the messages and even then I needed to turn on transport level logging to see them. They were not visible at service level
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DUO_RelatiefVerzuim_V13_Binding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging
             logEntireMessage="true"
             logMalformedMessages="true"
             logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
             logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
             maxMessagesToLog="3000"
             maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000000000"/>
      </diagnostics>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="d:\temp\trace.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>

